# Semantic Logging Application Block on Azure web role

Tags: azure, logging, etw, slab

I am planning use Semantic Logging Application Block in Web API hosted on Azure Web Role. I am planning to extend event source and create few event sources of mine.

I want to make sure that this component SLAB + Custom Event Source works properly on Azure Web Role.

Anyone has used this component on azure and want to share their experience?

Answer (score 1):

I use SLAB in my apps, however be sure that it can be used in the azure service you need to ask Microsoft support.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

for example at the bottom of the list you see that

Can listen to ETW events

is not supported for Web Sites but it seems to be fine for Web Roles. However, double check it with Azure support as caution is never enough.

Regards

Comment: is that mean we can not use SLAB with websites or webjobs ? We can not trace any event logging using SLAB?